# One-to-One relationship in database, foreign key should be in tableA or tableB?

Tags: sql, database

Example scenario: 1 employee will only have 1 address and 1 address will only own by that 1 employee.  Below are 2 options, which are correct or neither both?
More of my confusion is should I place Employee primary key into Address table or place Address primary key into Employee table?

I'm using PostgreSQL as some of you need to know which database am I using.

**Option 1**

```
Employee 
EmployeeId (PK) 
EmployeeName 
AddressId (FK)

Address 
AddressId (PK) 
AddressLine1
```

**Option 2**

```
Employee 
EmployeeId (PK) 
EmployeeName

Address 
AddressId (PK) 
AddressLine1 
EmployeeId (FK)
```

Comment: What if two employees live at the same address?  What happens when an employee moves?

Comment: If two employees live at the same address that would be fine because the primary key in the Address table will always be different.

If the employee moves the specific AddressId should be updated as well.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? It isn't really possible to have **true** 1:1 relationships unless your RDBMS supports deferred-constraints, and unfortunately (for example) MS SQL Server does not support them. An alternative approach is to use a `VIEW` that represents _valid_ paired data while the base-table is hidden from application code and queries.

Comment: I think you're being a bit too rigid - when it comes to storing mailing addresses for other entities in a `1:1` relationship it's easier just to make the `Address` table a simple _dumb_ store of data that contains no FKs of its own - which also allows you to use the `Addresses` table to store addresses for non-`Employee` records, like Customers.

Comment: Explain why you think two tables are needed.

Comment: @Dai I'm using PostgreSQL. When you mentioned I couldn't have 1:1 relationships is it because I have to at least create one record in one of the tables first and then get the inserted record's Id and then used as the foreign key in the other table?

Comment: @June7 sometimes I thought it is a good practice if the database table only contains its own relevant information as much as possible?

Comment: @AnonymousProgrammer You're in luck because Postgres **does** support deferrable constraints.

Comment: @June7 and also if we added other types of information wouldn't the Employee table be lengthy and containing many columns?

Comment: @AnonymousProgrammer "wouldn't the Employee table be lengthy and containing many columns" - that's very subjective.

Comment: Address is relevant to employee. It is information about employee. Doesn't everyone have an address or do you have homeless employees? If table has too many columns, most likely data is not normalized adequately. However, there are always exceptions to convention. I have one db that does employee 1-to-1 tables because there would be too many fields and I did not want to do more normalization.

Comment: @Dai I did see this option when I setting up my db, can you share with me what's wrong with the 2 options above?

Comment: @June7 normalization is one of the reasons I separated out into 2 tables. It is where we separate out the group of the relevant columns into a strong relevant table as much as possible right?

Comment: Normalization would be to prevent repetitive data, such as repeating a company full name in every order record. Also to prevent repetitive fields, like Product1, Product2, etc of an order. A 1-to-1 relationship is seldom needed. In my db I use 1-to-1 because it is for laboratory testing of construction samples. Each sample can have multiple tests and the tests required vary and each test has its own kind of data. Having all in one table would be too many fields. Each test has its own table and each sample can have 1 related record in any combination of test tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does an employee have an address, or, does an address have an employee?

I would say, an employee has an address. I would think of employees as having a primary key, and employee attributes.

employee table:

- employee id
- employee attributes
- ...

Whether or not an address needs a primary key is another question. But, if you then want to give an employee an additional attribute, "address", which resides in a separate table, I would first think of adding the foreign key in the address table to indicate to which employee this address belongs:

address table:

- employee id
- address attributes
- ...

Note that now, an employee may have multiple addresses, but two employees cannot share the same address.

If you want multiple employees to share the same address, you could, for example, introduce a primary key in the address table, and use an intermediate table:

address table:

- address id
- address attributes
- ...

employee_address table:

- employee id
- address id

In this case, both fields in the employee_address table are foreign keys. It would not make sense that these would be primary keys. Here, I think you would agree, the primary keys are in the employee and address tables.

To your original question then, I would naturally put the employee primary key into the address table, to show that an address belongs to an employee. But, it might not be as simple as that. You have to consider the use cases, such as whether or not two employees share the same address, and whether or not employees can have multiple addresses. Or, could employees not have an address, or, could an address not have any employees?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the specific database, so this answer assumes it implements constraint deferrability.

If you are absolutely sure the relationship is one to one, then one of the cleanest solutions is to share the primary key value and ensure you establish two symmetric foreign keys (from employee to address, and from address to employee).

```
Employee 
EmployeeId (PK) (FK)
EmployeeName 

Address 
AddressId (PK) (FK)
AddressLine1
```

In order to insert, update, or modify data, both FKs must be made *deferrable*. Deferrablity is a standard SQL feature that I know at least PostgreSQL and Oracle implement.

If you want to go a step further, the name of the PK in the `address` table can be `EmployeeId` instead of `AddressId`, to emphasize it's one and the same.

Comment: Another approach is to just inline the Address fields in the `Employee` table - that's the _only_ way to guarantee required `1:1` relationships in systems that don't support deferrable constraints without using tricks like `VIEW`s.

Comment: @Dai True, unless each table (employee and address) have their own relationships with other tables. If they become a single table, then all relationships get merged into a single super entity, something that may or may not be desirable. But yes, if there's no deferrability that's probably the best option.

Comment: I'm getting really frustrated at the amount of difficulty and counter-intuitiveness involved in modelling business/domain data and relationships in SQL databases now that I've been spoilt by languages like Rust and TypeScript which have allowed me to write succinct and extremely expressive code while also being _verifiably correct_ - but the opposite is true with relational databases: I haven't seen any fundamental improvements in data-modelling ability (besides deferrable-constraints). It's almost enough to make me want to go-off and write my own object-store database server...

Comment: @TheImpaler could you have a look at your answer with Kazi's answer? He suggested one table should be enough while you and Dai also suggesting having 2 tables with deferrable FK.

Comment: @AnonymousProgrammer Both approaches (single table. vs. multiple tables) **are valid** - we can't say which approach is better than the other without knowing more about your application and project requirements (as well as trying to anticipate likely future design decisions).

Comment: @Dai You shouldn't compare apples to oranges. Rust and TypeScript are programming languages that focus *processing* data, while databases are efficient at *storing* data.

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes, but both are concerned with data-modelling. I feel my comparison is appropriate because TypeScript and Rust make it easy to accurately model data for use in data-processing programs with few compromises for language shortcomings, but T-SQL’s DDL in SQL Server does *not* make it easy to model data storage in Cobb’s relational system, and I’m frequently finding myself needing to compromise my design due to limitations like the lack of deferrable constraints or table subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

For one to one relationship there is no reason to have multiple tables. Add address and AddressLine1 column into Employee table as below.

Employee
EmployeeId (PK)
EmployeeName
Address
AddressLine1

This will simplify your and ui design. And one to one relationship will be forced to be maintained without any constraint.

Comment: What if I have many one-to-one relationships won't the main table be added with many columns?

Comment: @AnonymousProgrammer There's no such thing as "too many columns" unless you tell us what "too many" _means_.

Comment: @AnonymousProgrammer I saw HR applications with 50 columns in Employee table along with many one to many relationship. And That application is running smoothly in more than 40 medium to big company.

Comment: I also have a table of 500 columns and the size of that table is 2.8 terabytes. It's working fine for me. So, your purpose will lead you how you should maintain your table. But too many unnecessary tables might increase complication.

Comment: @Dai I am not really sure "too many" is how many because I never exposed to a huge database before. I'm just assumed too many columns could cause performance issues and also my previous practice is what I have shown in the question, is that a bad practice??

Comment: @AnonymousProgrammer In short: **additional columns won't harm performance until benchmarks and profiling say otherwise** (or you hit your engine's internal limit. Postgres' limit is 1600 columns per table). I appreciate that it's very difficult for someone new to databases to have the right _mental heuristics_ about what is good vs. bad for performance: it's something you learn with experience - but generally speaking you *should not* compromise your design for _imagined_ performance reasons until and unless benchmarks and profiling says so.